# Why is the total energy of a satellite negative?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, potential-energy, conventions, satellites

I have learnt that the total energy of a satellite is negative because it is in a bounded system(closed system). Total energy of a satellite is defined as: $$\text{T.E.} = \text{K.E. + P.E.}$$ and this is negative because $$\text{P.E.} = \frac{-GMm}{r}$$ where $M$ is the mass of the planet, $m$ is the mass of the satellite and $r$ is the distance of satellite from the centre of the planet. But this is negative because I have chosen $\infty$ as the reference point. Since I am free to choose the reference point I want to choose $\frac{r}{2}$ as the reference point then after calculation I will get the potential energy $$\text{P.E.} = \frac{GMm}{r}$$ and total energy, $$\text{T.E.} = \frac{3GMm}{2r}$$ so this is positive, which contradicts the initial statement that the total energy of a closed system is always **negative**.
So where am I wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you've done here is the equivalent of deciding to contradict the statement "Water boils at 100 degrees" by deciding to use a temperature scale which sets its zero at the boiling point of iron.

Comment: I didn't understand. Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: You are free to make choices for your reference points, but not all reference points are equally useful. In choosing $r/2$ for the zero of gravitational potential, you've chosen one that isn't consistent between two different orbits around the same body, or for two points on the same elliptical orbit, and is _significantly_ less useful than using ∞.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bound system is a system (the system being the satellite) that can't reach infinity. We usually set $V(\infty)=0$ so a bound system has negative energy; however, you have defined $V(\infty) = +2GM/r$, so a bound system is one with energy less than $2GM/r$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the gravitational potential energy of a satellite being negative has anything to do with it being a closed system. As you have said, it is just because we have decided to use a reference point infinitely far away. This is a nice reference point to use, because it can be easily used with any object. In much the same way that defining altitude relative to sea level is convenient, and as a result most places on earth have a positive altitude above sea level.

As you said, using a different reference point could mean that the gravitational potential energy isn't negative.

Using infinity as our reference means that **ALL** gravitational potential energy is negative relative to infinity. Getting closer to a massive object like the earth can only make it more negative.

Comment: But it is given everywhere in the internet that the reason for which total energy of a satellite is negative is because it is in a bounded system.

Comment: It is the other way around. IF you choose the zero of PE at infinite distance, then the bound systems have negative energy.  If you choose another zero, then there is anothe condition for bound system.

Answer (score 0):

Two points on the same elliptical orbit will have different values of the radial distance $r$.

If you set the zero value on gravitational potential energy to $r/2$ for each point,  their Gravitational Potential energy values you get from them will be inconsistent with each other and , you don't have a reference *point*, you have a reference *ellipse*.

This will make describing Keplerian orbits much more difficult than it would be if you used the standard reference point, where Gravitational Potential is zero at infinity.